# Button Set Selected via BOOL

Tags: ios, uibutton, boolean

Can someone please educate me why the following does not work? The button never gets set to selected.

```
[self.boldButton setSelected:isBold];
```

If I replace the above with an if else statement it works fine. I can also change the setSelected values to 1 or 0, instead of YES or NO and it still works fine.

```
if (isBold)
{
    [self.boldButton setSelected:YES];
}
else
{
    [self.boldButton setSelected:NO];
}
```

So I have a working project, but I don't understand why these two implementations don't deliver the same results. Thanks.

FWIW - I test for bold with another method. Though if the test were flawed, I don't see how the second approach could work, while the first still doesn't.

```
- (BOOL)isBold
{
    CTFontRef fontRef = (CTFontRef)CFBridgingRetain(self);
    CTFontSymbolicTraits symbolicTraits = CTFontGetSymbolicTraits(fontRef);
    return (symbolicTraits & kCTFontTraitBold);
}
```

Comment: What is `isBold`? Is it declared as `BOOL isBold = YES`? That should work unless `isBold` is something else.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`BOOL` is defined like this in `<objc/objc.h>`:

```
typedef signed char     BOOL;
```

That means a `BOOL` can actually hold any value in the range -128 through 127 (inclusive).

`-[UIControl setSelected:]` works roughly like this:

```
#define kSelectedBitPosition 10
#define kSelectedBit (1 << kSelectedBitPosition)

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    if (((self->_controlFlags >> kSelectedBitPosition) & 1) == selected) {
        return;
    } else {
        self->_controlFlags = (self->_controlFlags & ~kSelectedBit)
            | ((selected & 1) << kSelectedBitPosition);
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

(I disassembled the simulator version of `UIKit` with [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com/) to figure that out.)

So, notice two things:

- The `if` statement condition can only be true if `selected == 0` or `selected == 1`.  It will never be true if `selected` has any other value.
- The assignment statement (that updates `_controlFlags`) only uses bit 0 (the 1's bit) of `selected`.  So, for example, if `selected == -2`, which is logically true in C and has every bit set *except* bit 0, the assignment statement will still not turn on the bit in `_controlFlags`.

This means that **you must pass 0 or 1** to `-[UIControl setSelected:]`.  No other value will work reliably.

The shortest way to convert all non-zero values to 1 in C is by applying the `!` operator twice:

```
[self.boldButton setSelected:!!isBold];
```

However, it would probably be better to fix your `-isBold` method to return a “safe” `BOOL` instead:

```
- (BOOL)isBold {
    CTFontRef fontRef = (CTFontRef)CFBridgingRetain(self);
    CTFontSymbolicTraits symbolicTraits = CTFontGetSymbolicTraits(fontRef);
    return !!(symbolicTraits & kCTFontTraitBold);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. So I take it that the if (isBold) else works from a valid BOOL trigger, but getting a value other than 0 or 1. Which is why my if else statement works.

Comment: Yes, your `if (isBold)` works because C treats *any* non-zero value as true in `if`, `while`, and `for` statements.