# Test More Than One Flag or Condition in NS_OPTIONS

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, enums, bit-manipulation

Here is what I want to do.  I have a simple NS_OPTIONS set up like

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, BuildingsPresent) {
    NoBuildings         = 0,
    LadderPresent       = 1 << 0,
    WallPresent         = 1 << 1,
    RoomPresent         = 1 << 2,
    RoomUpgradePresent  = 1 << 3
};
```

I'm setting the values like so:

```
self.buildingPresent |= LadderPresent | WallPresent;
```

This seems to work fine, but now I want to test the flags in an if statement all at once like so:

```
if (self.buildingPresent & LadderPresent & WallPresent) {
```

This is not working properly.  It does seem to work if I break it up into multiple if statements like so:

```
if (self.buildingPresent & LadderPresent) {
    if (self.buildingPresent & WallPresent) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I would also like to properly test for the lack of something as well, so the ideal way of writing this would be:

```
if (!(self.buildingPresent & RoomPresent) && (self.buildingPresent & LadderPresent & WallPresent) {
```

Is this possible in Objective-C?  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is your need with the 1st check? Do you want to see if at least those two bits are set or do you want to be sure only those two bits are set?

Comment: The need is to test that at least those two are set, but of course it could very well be useful to test if only some two are set in a different context.  Thanks for the responses everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (self.buildingPresent & LadderPresent & WallPresent)
```

This will always evaluate false.

The `&` operator returns a 1 only in the bit positions where both sides of the operator have the bit set to 1, and 0 in every other position.

`LadderPresent & WallPresent` have no positions for which both bits are 1, so they will always be all 0s.  And no matter what you `&` with all zeros will be all zeros, and therefore false.

If you intend to check if the `LadderPresent` bit AND the `WallPresent` bit are both active, you need to `OR` these together then `AND` the result to the variable:

```
if (self.buildingPresent & (LadderPresent | WallPresent)) {
```

This will return true for any value of `self.buildingPresent` so long as **EITHER** the `LadderPresent` and `WallPresent` bits are set to 1.

In order to verify that **BOTH** are set to 1, we must `AND` our variable to a mask that represents both being set to 1 and then see if that masks equals the masks we want:

```
NSInteger bitMask = (LadderPresent | WallPresent)
if ((self.buildingPresent & bitMask) == bitMask) {
```

This example will now return true only when BOTH are set to 1.

---

The proper way for testing for the lack of a bit looks more like this:

```
(self.buildingPresent & RoomPresent) == 0
```

This returns true when `self.buildingPresent` has a 0 in that position, and false when it has a 1.

Comment: Very helpful and thorough.  I completely understand what I was doing wrong.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the bit-twiddling expression in dasblinkenlight's answer directly, but I think your code will be more clear if you write a function to test for multiple flags:

```
BOOL hasFlags(NSUInteger actualFlags, NSUInteger desiredFlags) {
    return (actualFlags & desiredFlags) == desiredFlags;
}

...

    if (hasFlags(self.buildingPreset, LadderPresent | WallPresent)) {
        ...
    }
```

(NOTE: do **not** just `return actualFlags & desiredFlags;` in `hasFlags`.  That can return a “true” value that isn't `YES`, [which breaks some APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13750834/77567).)

Similarly, to check for a lack of all specified flags:

```
BOOL lacksFlags(NSUInteger actualFlags, NSUInteger forbiddenFlags) {
    return (actualFlags & forbiddenFlags) == 0;
}

...

    if (lacksFlags(self.buildingPresent, RoomPresent)
    && hasFlags(self.buildingPresent, LadderPresent | WallPresent)) {
        ...
    }
```